# Why does sugar make dough turn to liquid

Tags: food-chemistry

While making dango with a friend we decided to try to make the dough a bit sweeter.  We already had a large firm lump of dough (rice flour, glutinous rice flour and water) so we sprinkled a bit of sugar on top.  While kneading the dough in my hand I started to feel it run through my fingers.  The entire lump had turned into a goopy drippy mess.

Our best guess was that the sugar soaked up all the water, turning it into a bunch of flour particles in free flowing sugar water, but I cannot find any sources on the internet to explain what exactly happened.  Can anyone explain the reaction that causes this?

Comment: Possibly a question worth asking on [Seasoned Advice SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)